# Comment thread turning itself into a hate thread very quickly now

Tags: support, comments, specific-question, offensive

Can a few of the moderators take a look into this thread?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152165/intercept-facebook-chat-in-internet-explorer

Ed and opc0de are getting themselves into a quickly heating hate-thread.

Comment: +1. Used up all my comment flag posts on that one, also flagged the question itself. That kind of thing doesn't belong on stack overflow, it needs to be deleted as soon as possible.

Comment: Looks like it's 10k-only now... `[status-completed]`, I guess!

Comment: :) Thanks people; it is not visible for mere mortals any more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Next time just flag one of the comments for moderator attention. Use the 'other' option as briefly explain what is going on and what the moderators should do:

> Discussion is getting out of hand, please clean up the comments and talk to the somewhat overheated users name1 and name2.

Posting such a thread here only serves to call in more people that do *not* have the necessary access to shut it down and resolve disputes quietly. Leave that to the diamond mods instead.